# Make a div always 50% outside the viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

I want to create a circular element which is partly outside the viewport. It is not that complicated to create it, but its hard to make it consistant on different resolutions. As long as they stay 16:9 format, its fine, but when they differ from that, my element is moving anywhere making content inside unusable.

It should work like this, where the green rectangle is the viewport, the red circle my div outside it and the white rectangle is content inside the circle.

[image]

The html structure is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circlebox">
        <div class="circlecontent">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="">
            </div>
            <div class="infobox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circlebox {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vw;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:-30vw;
    top:-90vw;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.circlecontent {
    pointer-events: all;
    height:50%;
    width:65%;
    right:-5vw;
    padding:0 5vw;
    bottom:0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I tried to make the circle responsive to the window size by using vh and vw, but it doesn't really work.

Comment: Do you need your `.circlecontent` to be inside the `.circlebox`. If they are absolutely positioned, you could easily set your circle location based on the wrapper and also position the content this way as well, guaranteeing that your content will always be visible. Positioning the circle whilst keeping it responsive will be hard. Any time you use vw or percentages, you open up opportunities for you content to move unexpectedly. Using some `rem` values are my favourite but not always the correct solution. https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-lake-97ydct

Comment: Well thank you already. With rem its way more consistent. Still getting weird sometimes but a lot better.